# Why isn't my CSS menu animating when the checkbox is selected?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, css-grid

Clicking on the "Hamburger" button should make the menu, a styled flex, slide up from the bottom of the screen.

I have some styling here that's imposed by Wordpress, and other to help with managing styling at different screen sizes. I want to use Flexbox for the li elements for this reason.

I have copied the structure from working examples online. I don't understand why it doesn't work as implemented. I'm sure this is a stupid and obvious oversight. I haven't been deep in hands-on web development for years.

```
<div class="e-nav">

<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">

<header id="menu-box" class="menu-drawer">

<input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
<label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
    ) );
    ?>

</header>

</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

That HTML outputs as:

```
 <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">

            <header id="menu-box" class="menu-drawer">

                <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn"/>
                <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
                    <span class="navicon"></span>
                </label>

                <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/sample-page/">Archive</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/sample-page/">Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/sample-page/">Video</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/shop/">Shop</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/sample-page/">Follow</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/sample-page/">Colophon</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-21">
                            <a href="https://example.com/staging/5544/">foo</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>

        </nav>
        <!-- #site-navigation -->

    </div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
#e-page {
grid-template-columns: auto 100% auto;
}

.e-header {
grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
}

.e-content {
grid-area: 3 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
}

.e-footer {
grid-area: 4 / 1 / span 1 / span 3;
}

.e-nav {
position: fixed;
left: 0;    
bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: left;
} 

nav li {
flex-basis: 50%;
}

nav li:nth-child(7) {
flex-basis: 100%;
}

.menu {
max-height: 12em;
transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-icon {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
height: 3em;
width: 3em;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding: 1em;
position: fixed;
user-select: none;
z-index: 3;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-icon .navicon {
background: #FFF;
display: block;
height: 2px;
position: relative;
transition: background .2s ease-out;
width: 1em;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-icon .navicon:before {
background: #FFF;
content: '';
display: block;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
transition: all .2s ease-out;
width: 100%;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-icon .navicon:before {
top: 1em;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-btn {
display: none;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
max-height: 3em;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
top: .5em;
}

.menu-drawer .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.menu-drawer .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before {
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: need more css or url

Comment: Did you provide the codes carefully? When I put those CSS and html together I can only see some list items at the bottom left without any style.

Answer (score 0):

If it's hosted on Wordpress, that might be your problem. Does it work on the development server? I used Wordpress once and it was extremely janky. If I were you I would make a new Vite project https://vitejs.dev/guide/, copy all your files into the new project, and run your development server locally. Then host on Netlify https://www.netlify.com/ or something rather than Wordpress.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a selector. This was incorrect:

```
.menu-drawer .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
max-height: 3em;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

It should have been as follows:

```
.menu-drawer .menu-btn:checked ~ * .menu {
max-height: 12em;
}
```

It works now thanks to the wildcard. Wordpress adds its own ugly classes for UL elements. You could target them but I prefer to keep them out of the code. In that way when menus change, or the theme is used in new places, fewer things break because all the targeted classes are in the theme.